# Логирование в сервлетах

Tags: servlet, java-ee, java, сервлеты

Понятно что вопрос немного "дурной", но все же... Как Вы реализуете (считаете правильным реализовать) логирование в сервлетах. Т.е. дан `log4j;` задача реализовать логирование. Вопрос: как правильнее (учитывая издержки создания объектов и доступность `logger` в объектах) организовать логирование приложения (если в приложении использовать не только сервлеты, но и `plain old java class`)... использовать контекст или создавать объект каждый раз?

Answer (score 2):

Сервлеты создаются контэйнером (веб-сервером) только один раз, поэтому распростаненная практика держать экземпляр логгера в статической переменной внутри класса тут ничему не повредит, наверное. Можно воспользоваться возможностями логгирования, которые уже предоставляет сервлет-контейнер (метод log сервлетаа).

Comment: сервлеты создаются(выбираются из пула) на КАЖДЫЙ ЗАПРОС юзера(в общем случае браузера)...логирование необходимо реализовать Log4j...

Comment: Интересно где же вы такое прочитали, все современные сервлет-контейнеры создают экземпляр сервлета один раз. Кладите экземпляр логгера в private static final :).

Comment: Простите...некорректно выразился...экз. сервлета создается один раз, на каждое обращение юзера создается объект запроса который выполняется в отдельном потоке...т.е. насколько я понимаю мы получаем многопоточность? 
Далее я знаю что можно создать static ссылку на объект типа Logger, так-же я знаю что можно реализовать SimpleFactory(создать сервлет, получить в нем ссылку на Logger и передать это в контекст).
Хотелось-бы услышать мнение по поводу плюсов и минусов данных реализаций(так-же и в контексте использования  Nested Diagnostic Context & Mapped Diagnostic Context)